# Converting variable length time-series into constant length

Tags: time-series

I have a set of time series that are of variable length. I intend to bring them to a particular length (preferably the median length) in order to analyze them. I was hoping that I could get some techniques to do the same.

P.S - I heard that interpolation works well for such kinds of problems. Would interpolation allow me to reduce the length of the time-series, for instance bring the longest time series to median length?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you manipulate your time series, you are going to alter its temporal behaviour.
Any interpolation method you use must incorporate not just space related information (observations) but also their temporal (time domain) related properties.